# Flutter CupertinoPageRoute duration

Tags: flutter

How do I add a duration to the CupertinoPageRoute? Currently it slides too quick and the effect is not very good.

```
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    CupertinoPageRoute<Null>(
      builder: (context) => View(),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: checkout this https://medium.com/flutter-community/everything-you-need-to-know-about-flutter-page-route-transition-9ef5c1b32823

Answer (score 1):

My solution was not via CupertinoPageRoute, but maybe it can help.

Create a Route that you can customise:

```
Route yourCustomRoute() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
     pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => YourView(),
     transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        var begin = Offset(-0.1, -0.1); //start position from top and left corner f.e.
        var end = Offset.zero;
        var curve = Curves.ease;

        var tween =
           Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

        return SlideTransition(
           position: animation.drive(tween),
           child: child,
        );
      },
      transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 10) //any duration you want      
   );
}
```

Add your route to Navigator:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(yourCustomRoute());
```

Read about routing between two pages here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation

Comment: thank you. I'll try it and let you know how it works.